# How to treeshake asset object that requires multiple images (url and file loader)

Tags: javascript, webpack, tree-shaking

I've got 1 js file that exports requires to certain images in following manner:

```
export const assets = {
  UI: {
    BUTTON_GREEN: require('../assets/minified/ui/button_green_background.png'),
    BUTTON_YELLOW: require('../assets/minified/ui/button_yellow_background.png'),
  },
  BACKGROUNDS: {
    BACKGROUND_FIRE: require('../assets/minified/bg/background_fire.jpg'),
  }
};
/* etc... */
```

I then use this in various pages as follows

```
import {assets} from "./assets.js"

<img src={assets.UI.BUTTON_GREEN} />
```

I do this as it is easier to import images when using typescript due to autocomplete. I then have following loaders in my webpack config

```
  {
    test: /\/ui\/[^.]+\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/,
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
      name: 'static/images/[name]-[hash].[ext]',
      limit: 50000,
      esModule: false
    }
  },
  {
    test: /\/bg\/[^.]+\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/,
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      name: 'static/images/[name]-[hash].[ext]',
      esModule: false
    }
  }
```

I use separate loaders in order to inline ui elements and parse other bigger images as normal files. I set `esModule` to `false` because otherwise I am not able to get my requires working for some reason, as they return 'default' instead of string related to image.

I then have my pages split into their own js chunks i.e.

```
Page                        Size
┌ * /                       74 kB
├   /_app                   1.25 MB
├   /_document
├   /_error                 9.43 kB
├ * /registration/sign-in  697 B
└ * /registration/sign-up    438 B
```

but as you can see my `_app` got over 1mb, this is due to me inlining some ui images and they are all spit into this one file, even though it uses just 2 images.

So my question is: how can I restructure my approach in order to only add inlined image data to js chunks of pages that use it? I am open to additional loader settings / restructuring my asset file etc...

Comment: I'm not an expert in this field so I cannot give you concrete answer but as far as I know `require` is synchronous, so you could export every asset separately `export const UI_BUTTON_GREEN = require...`and use named imports in pages like `import {UI_BUTTON_GREEN} from './assets.js'` OR use `import(..)` which is async and could load only used assets dynamically

Comment: @kaczmen just restructured my app to this, same result when using requires, will try  to figure out how to get this working with import